# Setting default values to a form on codeigniter

Tags: sql, forms, codeigniter

Sorry dudes, this is my first question, i've been dwelling your site for a little while and learnt a lot, but now i have a problem myself that couldn't find an answer, the thing is that i have a form that's filled in two diferent views, one to select a course that will be edited on the second one, the second one should have all the fields already filled with those that equals them on the database, i know that setting default values should be done using the set_value function defining a second parameter but it isn't working, everything else seems fine...

THIS IS MY FIRST VIEW

```
<?php echo link_tag('assets/css/nuevocurso.css');?>

<div id="infoMessage"><?php echo $message ?></div>

<section class="container">
    <div class="register">
        <h1>Ingrese el código del curso que desea modificar.</h1>
        <?php echo form_open("curso/modificarcurso");?>

        <p> <i>Código</i> <br /> <?php echo form_input($codigo);?> </p>

        <p class="submit"><?php echo form_submit('commit', "Registrarse");?></p> 

        <?php echo form_close();?>

    </div>
  </section>
  <br/>
```

THIS IS MY SECOND VIEW

```
<?php echo link_tag('assets/css/nuevocurso.css');?>

<div id="infoMessage"><?php echo $message ?></div>

<section class="container">
    <div class="register">
        <h1>Modifique los atributos de curso que desee.</h1>
        <?php echo form_open("curso/gestionarcurso");?>

        <p> <i>Nombre</i> <br /> <?php echo form_input($nombre);?> </p>

        <p> <i>Descripcion</i> <br /> <?php echo form_textarea($descripcion);?> </p>

        <p> <i>Codigo</i> <br /> <?php echo form_input($codigo);?> </p>

        <p> <i>Alias</i> <br /> <?php echo form_input($alias);?> </p>

        <p> <i>Programa</i> <br /> <?php echo form_textarea($programa);?> </p>




        <p class="submit"><?php echo form_submit('commit', "Registrarse");?></p> 

        <?php echo form_close();?>

    </div>
  </section>
  <br/>
```

AND THIS MY CONTROLLER

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Modificarcurso extends CI_Controller 
{

    public function index()
    {
    $this->load->database();
    $this->load->library('ion_auth');
    $this->load->model('nuevocurso_model');
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');        
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('codigo', 'Código', 'required|xss_clean');
    $user = $this->ion_auth->user()->row();
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == true)
        {
            $codigo = $this->input->post('codigo');
            echo $codigo;
            $flag = $this->db->query("SELECT codigo FROM curso WHERE codigo = '".$codigo."'");
            $flag = $flag->result_array();
            var_dump($flag);
            if ($user->es_admin == 1 && !empty($flag))
                    {
                    echo "chupala maraco";
                    $this->data['codigo']= $codigo;
                    $this->data['tipo'] = "admin";
                    $this->manage($this->data);
                    }
            $flag = $this->db->query("SELECT codigo FROM dicta_curso_profesor WHERE rut = '".$user->rut."' AND codigo = '".$codigo."'");
            $flag = $flag->result_array();      
            if ((!empty($flag))&&($user->es_admin!=1)&&($user->es_profesor==1))
                {
                    $this->data['codigo'] = $codigo;
                    $this->data['tipo'] = "profesor";
                    $this->manage($this->data);
                }
            if ($this->db->affected_rows()>0) 
                {
                    $this->data['message'] = 'EEEEEXITO';
                }
            else
                {
                    $this->data['message'] = 'HAHAHAHAHA';
                }
            }


            $this->data['codigo'] = array(
                'name'  => 'codigo',
                'id'    => 'codigo',
                'type'  => 'text',
                'value' => $this->form_validation->set_value('codigo'));
            echo $user->es_admin;
            echo $user->es_profesor;
            $this->load->view('home/header_view');
            $this->load->view('curso/gestionarcursoredirect',$this->data);
            $this->load->view('home/footer_view');

        }


    public function manage($datos)
    {
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->helper('html');
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $user = $this->ion_auth->user();
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('nombre','Nombre','required|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('alias','Alias','required|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('codigo','Codigo','required|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('descripcion','Codigo','required|xss_clean');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == true)
        {
            $nombre = $this->input->post('nombre');
            $alias = $this->input->post('alias');
            $descripcion = $this->input->post('descripcion');
            $codigo = $this->input->post('codigo');
            $rutprofesor = $this->input->post('profesor');
            $flag = $this->db->query("SELECT nombre, codigo FROM curso WHERE curso.nombre = '".$nombre."' OR curso.codigo = '".$codigo."'");
            $flag = $flag->result_array();
            if (empty($flag))
                    {
                        $query = $this->db->query("INSERT INTO curso (nombre, alias, codigo, descripcion) VALUES ('".$nombre."','".$alias."','".$codigo."','".$descripcion."')");
                        $query = $this->db->query("INSERT INTO dicta_curso_profesor (rut, codigo) VALUES ('".$rutprofesor."','".$codigo."')");
                    }
            if ($this->db->affected_rows()>0) 
                                {
                                    $this->data['message'] = 'EEEEEXITO';
                                }
            else
                                {
                                    $this->data['message'] = 'HAHAHAHAHA';
                                }
        }


        $codigo = $this->input->post('codigo');
        $curso = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM curso WHERE curso.codigo = '".$codigo."'");
        $curso = $curso->result_array();
        var_dump($curso);
        echo $curso[0]['nombre'];
        $this->data['nombre'] = array(
                'name'  => 'nombre',
                'id'    => 'nombre',
                'type'  => 'text',
                'value' => $this->form_validation->set_value('nombre', $curso[0]["nombre"]),
        );

        $this->data['descripcion'] = array(
                'name'  => 'descripcion',
                'id'    => 'descripcion',
                'type'  => 'text',
                'value' => $this->form_validation->set_value('descripcion', $curso[0]['descripcion']),
                'maxlength' => '300',
                'rows' => '5',
                'cols' => '35',
        );
        $this->data['codigo'] = array(
                'name' => 'codigo',
                'id'   => 'codigo',
                'type' => 'text',
                'value' => $this->form_validation->set_value('codigo', $curso[0]['codigo']),
                'maxlength' => '8',
        );
        $this->data['programa'] = array(
                'name' => 'programa',
                'id' => 'programa',
                'type' => 'text',
                'value' => $this->form_validation->set_value('programa', $curso[0]["programa"]),
        );
        $this->data['alias'] = array(
                'name' => 'alias',
                'id'   => 'alias',
                'type' => 'text',
                'value'=> $this->form_validation->set_value('alias', $curso[0]["alias"]),
                'maxlength' => '14',
        );
        $this->data['profesores'] = $this->nuevocurso_model->get_profesores();
        $this->load->view('home/header_view');
        $this->load->view('curso/gestionarcurso',$this->data);
        $this->load->view('home/footer_view');
    }
}
```

the set_value are in the last function called manage on the controller, those are not working, don't worry about the model, i'm not yet using the only function stored in it.

Thank you, people, stackoverflow is amazing!

Comment: `$this->data` => $data should be declared as class variable in your controller.

Answer (score 0):

The CodeIgniter form helper expects two arguments if you want to set the value, example:

```
echo form_input('nombre', $nombre);
```

As the manual says: "You can minimally pass the field name and value in the first and second parameter"

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html

Comment: That doesn't just set default values, that let's you set prior values as well.

Answer (score 0):

Will it work in your view like this:

```
echo form_input(array('name' => 'codigo', 'id' => 'codigo'), set_value('codigo', 'YOUR_VALUE'));
```